# Comparing 6 int arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to solve a puzzle by programing it. I have int 6 arrays and each one has 6 numbers. I have to choose one number from each one to come up with a sum of 419.
I'm almost a beginner in Java. I tried to use if() elseif()
ex: `if (lock1[i]+lock2[i]+lock4[i]+lock4[i]+lock5[i]+lock6[i] == 419)`
 but it was too long code.
I looked up at Java API for Array and ArrayList classes but I couldn't figure out which method I should use

here is the arrays

```
 class Locks {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int [] lock1 = {39,6,75,88,15,57};
            int [] lock2 = {9,2,58,68,48,64};
            int [] lock3 = {29,55,16,67,8,91};
            int [] lock4 = {40,54,66,22,32,25};        
            int [] lock5 = {49,1,17,41,14,30};
            int [] lock6 = {44,63,10,83,46,3};
            int total = 419;
          }
    }
```

Comment: another approach (not so efficient) is to brute force with 6 loop (or recursion), and try all combinations

Comment: Put the arrays in an ArrayList, the use enhanced for loop to iterate through it and make addition

Comment: By hand, there aren't many high numbers... @Ragavan or for (int[] a : /*int[][]*/ locks)

Comment: Another way of doing it(a complicated one) is to generate all the possible combinations of 6 indexes and check if values from those add up to your desired sum. Getting values for given indexes would be O(1) operation but I am not sure how efficient would be generating all permutations  of indexes would be and whether it is a better option then the brute force method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It prints: 3, 3, 5, 0, 0, 3 which refers to
88, 68, 91, 40, 49, 83.

The key thing to understand is that we need to look at 6 ^ 6 combinations. Therefore we generate numbers from 0 to 6 ^ 6 -1.

```
public class Locks{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][] locks = {
            {39,6,75,88,15,57},
            {9,2,58,68,48,64},
            {29,55,16,67,8,91},
            {40,54,66,22,32,25},        
            {49,1,17,41,14,30},
            {44,63,10,83,46,3}};
        int i, j;
        int total = 419;
        int dims = 6;               // number of dimensions in array
        int loops = 1; 
        for(i = 0; i < dims; ++i)   // maximum number of elements to test 
             loops *= dims;
        for(i=0; i < loops; ++i) {  // loop over all possibilities
            int cTotal = 0;         // Total for this selection of 6 columns
            int rTotal = 1;
            for(j = 0; j < dims; ++j) {       // generate six array indexes
                cTotal += locks[j][i / rTotal % dims];
                rTotal *= dims;
            }
            rTotal = 1;
            if(cTotal == total) {
                for(j = 0; j < dims; ++j) {
                    System.out.println(i / rTotal % dims);
                    rTotal *= dims;
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one! it found the answer and worked very well.. it's a little bit complicated for me as an amateur .. I'm trying to solve puzzles to learn.

Comment: Cool! It was a fun question to think about!

Comment: @user814064 can you point out the complexity of this solution?

Comment: It's N^N. It tests every possibility. It can run up to 46656 times through the loop.

Comment: So, technically speaking it doen't give us any performance improvement over solution proposed by Ragvan or does it?

Comment: It's not faster. It doesn't hardcode the size of the array. We could run it on a 7 * 7 or 5 * 5 without changing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Tset {

static int [] lock1 = {39,6,75,88,15,57};
static int [] lock2 = {9,2,58,68,48,64};
static int [] lock3 = {29,55,16,67,8,91};
static int [] lock4 = {40,54,66,22,32,25};
static int [] lock5 = {49,1,17,41,14,30};
static int [] lock6 = {44,63,10,83,46,3};
static int [] index =  new int[6];
static int total = 419;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(Tset.getIndex()!=null){

    }

}


    public static int[] getIndex(){
        int total1 =0;
        for(int i1 :lock1){
              for(int i2 :lock2){
                  for(int i3 :lock3){
                      for(int i4 :lock4){
                          for(int i5 :lock5){
                              for(int i6 :lock6){
                                       total1=lock1[i1]+lock2[i2]+lock4[i3]+lock4[i4]+lock5[i5]+lock6[i6];
                                    if (total1==total) {
                                             index[0] = i1;
                                             index[1] = i2;
                                             index[2] = i3;
                                             index[3] = i4;
                                             index[4] = i5;
                                             index[5] = i6;
                                        return index;
                                    }

                              }

                          }

                      }

                  }

              }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

}

Comment: It is one way of doing it. I am just curios is it the only way of doing it?

Comment: I think only way is bruteforce method which is handled in the above code. You can move the code here and there come up with slightly different code but the idea is same

Comment: There's no reason not to write it simply as it's only 47000 cases. As a general problem with `k` locks of `k` numbers under 1000, say, it might be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

This solution can work with any set of arrays and can find more than all combinations producing the required sum

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[] lock1 = { 39, 6, 75, 88, 15, 57 };
    int[] lock2 = { 9, 2, 58, 68, 48, 64 };
    int[] lock3 = { 29, 55, 16, 67, 8, 91 };
    int[] lock4 = { 40, 54, 66, 22, 32, 25 };
    int[] lock5 = { 49, 1, 17, 41, 14, 30 };
    int[] lock6 = { 44, 63, 10, 83, 46, 3 };
    int[][] locks = { lock1, lock2, lock3, lock4, lock5, lock6 };
    int[] a = new int[6];
    find(locks, 0, a, 419);
}

static void find(int[][] locks, int i, int[] a, int x) {
    if (i < locks.length) {
        for (int j = 0; j < locks[i].length; j++) {
            a[i] = j;
            int n = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
                n += locks[k][a[k]];
            }
            if (n == x) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
            }
            find(locks, i + 1, a, x);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When writing such a loop, note that there is a small optimization to be had by saving a working total. Same asymptotic time of course, but certainly fewer operations.

```
   int sum = lock1[0]+lock2[0]+lock4[0]+lock4[0]+lock5[0]+lock6[0];
   for(int i1 :lock1){
       sum += lock1[i1];
            ...
               ...
                   for(int i6 :lock6){
                       sum += lock6[i6];
                       //test total=sum  
                       sum -= lock6[i6];
                   }
               ...
            ...
       sum -= lock1[i1];
   }
```